# How to download a file using FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to convert an API created in Flask into FastAPI, which demonstrates how to download a file from the server; however, I don't know how to change the code below:

```
@app.route('/download/<fname>', methods=['GET'])
def download(fname):
 return send_file(fname)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a very easily google-able problem. Here's one link that comes up and solves your problem after googling for 3 seconds: https://betterprogramming.pub/migrate-from-flask-to-fastapi-smoothly-cc4c6c255397

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Download a File after POSTing data using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73234675/how-to-download-a-file-after-posting-data-using-fastapi)

Comment: Related answers can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72053557/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241648/17865804).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends of what kind of file you're trying to download. But you can find good information here: [FastApi Streaming Response](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse)

In your case it would be something like:

```
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

@app.get("/download")
async def download(fname : str):
 file_like = open(fname, mode="rb")
 return StreamingResponse(file_like, media_type="type of your file")
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the response, I wanted to download a blob file of azure storage blob.