# How to return and download Excel file using FastAPI?

Tags: python, excel, fastapi, media-type

How do I return an excel file (version: Office365) using FastAPI?  The documentation seems pretty straightforward.  But, I don't know what `media_type` to use.  Here's my code:

```
import os
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

excel_file_path = r"C:\Users\some_path\the_excel_file.xlsx"

app = FastAPI()

class ExcelRequestInfo(BaseModel):
    client_id: str


@app.post("/post_for_excel_file/")
async def serve_excel(item: ExcelRequestInfo):
    # (Generate excel using item.)
    # For now, return a fixed excel.
    return FileResponse(
        path=excel_file_path,

        # Swagger UI says 'cannot render, look at console', but console shows nothing.
        media_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'

        # Swagger renders funny chars with this argument:
        # 'application/vnd.ms-excel'
    )
```

Assuming I get it right, how to download the file? Can I use Swagger UI generated by FastAPI to view the sheet? Or, curl?  Ideally, I'd like to be able to download and view the file in Excel.

**Solution**

Here's my final (edited) solution to save you from clicking about.  In the course of development, I had to switch from a `FileResponse` to `Response` that returns `io.BytesIO`.

```
import io
import os.path
from fastapi.responses import Response


@router.get("/customer/{customer}/sheet")
async def generate_excel(customer: str):
    excel_file_path: str = None
    buffer: io.BytesIO = None

    # Generate the sheet.
    excel_file_path, buffer = make_excel(customer=customer)

    # Return excel back to client.
    headers = {
        # By adding this, browsers can download this file.
        'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename={os.path.basename(excel_file_path)}',
        # Needed by our client readers, for CORS (cross origin resource sharing).
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
        "Access-Control_Allow-Methods": "POST, GET, OPTIONS",
    }
    media_type = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'

    return Response(
        content=buffer.getvalue(),
        headers=headers,
        media_type=media_type
    )
```

Comment: To enable CORS, I would suggest having a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75048778/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76768156/17865804)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could set the [`Content-Disposition` header using the `attachment` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#as_a_response_header_for_the_main_body), indicating to the browser that the file should be downloaded, as described in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71728386/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804). Swagger UI will provide a `Download file` link for you to download the file, as soon as you execute the request.

```py
headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="Book.xlsx"'}
return FileResponse(excel_file_path, headers=headers)
```

To have the file viewed in the browser, one can use the `inline`, instead of `attachment`, parameter in the `Content-Disposition` header, as explained in the linked answers earlier. However, for the browser to be able to display the Excel file, one should set the correct `media_type` in the [`FileResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#fileresponse) (for Excel files see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974079/setting-mime-type-for-excel-document)), as well as `.xlsx` (or `.xls`) must be a known file extension to the browser (this is usually achieved through browser extensions/plug-ins).